# JList adding and removing items (Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jlist

I'm trying to add and remove items from my jList (jList1), but It doesn't work.
I've searched on stackoverflow for other people with the same problem, but when their problem is solved, I keep getting errors.
So this is how I declared the jList:

```
jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
        String [] strings = lijstItems;
        public int getSize() {
            return strings.length;
        }
        public Object getElementAt (int i) {
            return strings[i];
        }
    });
```

So now I made these buttons to add and remove items from the list:

```
private void addHostActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) jList1.getModel();
    model.add(2, "item");
    // THIS DOES NOT WORK...

}
```

And

```
private void deleteHostActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:

}
```

I've tried so many things, but they don't work!
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set the model of the list to an `AbstractListModel`. You *can't* cast the model to a `DefaultListModel`. Trying to do so will give you a `ClassCastException` So set the model to a `DefaultListModel` instead.

```
jList1.setModel(new DefaultListModel());
```

And you probably want to use [`DefaultListModel#addElement(element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement%28E%29) instead of adding the element to same index every time, with `add(2, element)`

Comment: Okay, but when I set the model to an AbstractListModel, I can't use the model.addList method?

    AbstractListModel model = (AbstractListModel) jList1.getModel();
    model.addList(index,"string"); //addList gives an error

Comment: I didn't tell you do cast to `AbstractListModel`. I said the set the model to a `DefaultListModel`. `AbstractListeModel` _has no_ data manipulation methods

Comment: So if I have to set the model to `AbstractListModel` and cast it to `DefaultListModel`, you say it should work?

But when I try, I can't use the `.addElement`

Comment: NO That is what you are already doing. And it's _not_ working. If you're using Netbeans GUI Builder, just right click on the list, and go to properties. Click the ellipses in the `model` property. Go to `custom code` from the drop down and just type in `new DefaultListModel()`. You'll probably have to resolve imports afterward. Just go to your source and hit Ctrl+Shift+O

Comment: There are no 'ellipses' in the model property. I'm running NetBeans 7.3.1 for Mac OS X.

Comment: Is there not a small little button on the very right of the property that you can click

Comment: of course there is, but that's for editing the items manually.

Comment: The dialog you're referring to is where the drop down I'm talking about. If it's not there, then I don't know, must be a mac thing. You can then just set the model in the constructor instead, after initComponents()

Comment: Even when you select "custom code"? If you can't then just do what I said an type in the constructor, after `initComponents()` in the source code. `jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultListModel());`.Then

Comment: I think I changed it, but when I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: I couldn't tell you what you're doing wrong then, without seeing more code. If you set the model to DefautListModel and in you actionPerformed you're doing `DefaultListModel model  = (DefaultListModel)jList1.getModel();
        model.addElement("Hello");`, There's no reason it shouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

> this is how I declared the jList:

Why are you creating a custom ListModel? Just use the DefaultListModel. There is no need for you to create a custom model to simply store String data.

Then you can read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example that does exactly what you want by using the "Hire" and "Fire" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the existing items in the JList and add new ones, I had to get the model ListModel and then add the items to DefaultListModel as the ListModel does not have an addElement method. This is how I implemented:

```
   DefaultListModel<String> model = new  DefaultListModel<String>();
   ListModel model2 = jList.getModel();
   for (int i=0; i< model2.getSize();i++){
        model.addElement(model2.getElementAt(i).toString());              
        }
   model.addElement("new element");
   jList.setModel(model);
```